# Multiple routes for static html pages in Express

Tags: node.js, express

I am trying to serve 2 static HTML pages from Express but whilst the index.html is correctly served I get an error when I try to access the /about route:

> Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat
>   '/var/www/html/myapp/about.html'
>       at Error (native)

```
var express = require('express'),
  app = express(),
  http = require('http'),
  httpServer = http.Server(app);

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/html_files'));

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.sendfile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

app.get('/about', function(req, res) {
  res.sendfile(__dirname + '/about.html');
});


app.listen(3000);
```

I can update the '/about.html' to '/html_files/about.html' and then it works but whilst this solves the issue I can't understand why it wouldn't work as it is.

Comment: Your static routes need to point to a file like this: `__dirname + '/html_files/about.html'`, not just: `__dirname + '/about.html'`

Answer (score 0):

Looks correct.

`app.get('/'...` will be ignored, as server already has found static `index.html` matching this request.

`app.get('/about'...` fails because of incorrect url to file you're trying to send. If you ask for `/about.html` it'll be sent by static middleware correctly.

Comment: Please can you explain what you mean because I have written many examples and cannot get the /about.html to be sent without typing the actual directory name as well which, if that's the case, what's the purpose of the express.static?  This does not work: app.get('/about', function(req, res) {
  res.sendfile('about.html');
});

Comment: express.static just set directory, from which by default use can easily get files directly. E.g. `http://example.com/about.html` will return your about.html. If with static you need it to work with the same url, put it to `/your_public/about/index.html`. If you still want about.html on `/about` request, you'll need more manipulations. I have no solutions for this implementation